# registeration_activation_hook WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a question about the `register_activation_hook` in WordPress.  Let me give an example.  Let's say....

Main Plugin File:

```
//main_plugin_file.php

register_activation_hook( __FILE__,  'activate'  );

function activate(){

    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'classes/class-config.php';

    $config  = new config();

    $config->activate_function();

}
```

Class File:

```
//class-config.php

class config {

    public function __construct(){

        add_action( 'query_vars', array( $this, 'sample_one' ) );

        add_filter( 'init', array( $this, 'sample_two' ) );

        add_action( 'wp_loaded', array( $this, 'sample_three' ) );

    }

    public function activate_function(){

        $this->insert_user_into_database();

    }

    public function insert_user_into_database (){

     //execution code here....

   }
```

My question is once I activate this plugin, does the `__construct` function in the Config class run too? or the function in "activate_function" run?, which run first? I was confused because I have the `$config = new config();` and whenever there is a "new" keyword", the `__construct` function is automatically run.  Please help me understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `main_plugin_file.php` code:

1. `activate()` will run when the plugin is activated, due to `register_activation_hook`

   - You load in your `class-config.php` file, but nothing happens because it just defines the class, but the `config` class hasn't been called/instantiated yet - it's purely been defined.
2. When you call `$config = new config();`, that's where you instantiate the class and the `__construct` function is run.
3. `$config->activate_function();` will now run.

If you were to comment out this line `// $config  = new config();` then the `__construct` function wouldn't ever run, because when you `require` the `class-config.php` file, it's not actually running the internal functions. Classes only run when you call them, such as `$var = new Class();` - *not* when they are defined.

It's similar to this basic function example, this file:

```
<?php function foo(){
    echo 'bar';
} ?>
```

Will never output anything, because the function `foo` has been defined, but it doesn't *run* until we call `foo()` later.

Here's a simple sandbox function, you can see it only echos the once, because we define the class, but nothing happens until we instantiate it by calling `new MyClass()`:

[Sandbox Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/000695fc7f86503119506690cbc7e9178981e14d)

Comment: Thank you Xhynk for your help.  So when I click on the "activate" button to activate the plugin, the following will run....1. register_activation_hook( __FILE__,  'activate'  ); 2. function activate (); 3. $config = new config(); (this statement cause the __construct() function to automatically run); 4. $this->activate_function().

Comment: Yes indeed, that's exactly what will happen